# Dual citizenship UK & NZ

Tags: passports

My son has dual citizenship. We moved from NZ to the US a couple of years ago. We are about to move to the UK. He entered the US on his NZ passport. As we’ll be living in the UK, do we use his British passport when we go to the UK to live?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course.  Why wouldn't you?

Comment: @phoog I think the OP is wondering about getting stamped exiting USA on the same passport they arrived with (NZ), to save future complications. And then entering the UK with the British passport. I guess that's all legal but I can't back up my guess with evidence.

Comment: Since passports are not stamped on exit in the US, it really doesn't matter...

Comment: @user16259 see dda's comment. The main worry would be failure to have the departure recorded electronically, but that's not a particularly significant problem.  Depending on the son's immigration status in the US, which we do not know, it might not be a problem at all.

Comment: Use the NZ passport on your way out of the US, including booking the tickets (so the airline records the exit with US immigration), but present your UK passport at UK immigration. Best of both worlds.